# data.table filter and count uniques

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` of the following format

```
Class    Value1  Value2
1         10      20
1         10      15
1         15      0
0          4      40
0          4      50
```

I want to subset the three rows that are `Class =1`  and then count the number of `unique` values in `Value1` in that subsetted data.
So my answer in this case would be `2`
Tried `unique([dt[, 'Value1', by='Class'])` but that didnt work.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, is an option with `data.table` where we subset the rows by specifying logical expression in `i`, then get the count of `unique` values of the column 'Value1' with `uniqueN`

```
library(data.table)
dt[Class == 1, .(un_val1 = uniqueN(Value1))]
```

Comment: Thank you! The only follow-on I had was if I stored the ````Class```` in a variable like `````class_var='Class'```` I see that dt[c(class_var)==1, .(un_val1 = uniqueN(Value1))]```` does not behave the same way. Any thoughts on how I can achieve a similar result with variable that has the column name?

Comment: @FlyingPickle For that you can use several options i.e. `dt[get(class_var) == 1,` or with `dt[eval(as.name(class_var)) == 1,`